# Can't see list options after adding content editor

Tags: list-view, sharepoint-calendar

I have a calendar list, using the calendar view, to which I have added a content editor Web Part, to contain additional instructions about the calendar.  I added that Web Part directly to the calendar.aspx page using "Edit Page".

Now, when I'm viewing that page, there is NO Calendar tab at the top of the screen.  It was there before I added the Web Part.  I am trying to get into the list settings and I can't.  I know I could go to a certain URL or go in through Sharepoint Designer but that's beside the point -- why do my Calendar/List options disappear and how can I get them back?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  It appears that the Content Editor Web Part has the "focus" when the page is first loaded, and the ribbon contents seem to be determined by the context of the Web Part that has focus, rather than having all the commands for all web parts on the page.  When I click on any area within the Calendar Web Part, lo and behold, my options appear in the ribbon.  Unless there is a specific style element that we don't have set up right, there is no visible indication that I can see of which Web Part has focus (short of, I presume, a blinking cursor in a text field if one is present).  Interestingly, if I click on "Add" on a calendar event, the Web Part still doesn't gain focus (Calendar ribbon options don't appear) but yet my Add Event dialog appears.

I'm about halfway to calling this a bug.  It's not quite a bug but it's more than a "feature".  Not sure where that leaves it.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on 'all items' view it should produce the list ribbon.   I also created a 'work' view and that also produces the list ribbon.