# Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise Calendar "Event" and "Calendar" Tabs not showing

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-calendar

I added several new Calendar apps to my site and, when I open them, most show the tabs "Browse", "Events" and "Calendar" (the latter allows a user to connect the calendar to outlook). However some of them only show the "Browse" tab so the user is unable to connect. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I discovered the reason from another post. Here:- [Can't see list options after adding content editor](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53431/cant-see-list-options-after-adding-content-editor)

You need to make sure the actual calendar has focus not the container.